# Asynctask status after App is crashed

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Once Asynctask is in Progress (in doinbackground state) the ANR window appears , the app got crashed. What will be the status of asynctask? It will be stopped or will continue until the task completion .

Comment: please put your code here

Comment: It may possible that you are updating your UI in doinbackground()

Comment: post your asynctask code, you must be doing heavy work in post execute who is blocking your main thread